# Unexpected behavior by DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS T-SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetimeoffset

T-SQL function DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS does not seem to allow non-zero minutes in the offset portion, i.e., the 9-th input parameter.

I have tried various combinations of defining the DateTimeOffset data type with precisions other than zero, all to no avail. Can't think of a workaround except perhaps assembling a character string in datetimeoffset format; that would probably work, but I'd like to see whether DateTimeOffsetFromParts is having a problem, or is it myself?

```
-- Unexpected behavior by DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS function, SQL Server 2014
DECLARE @sStatus nvarchar(MAX) = 'OK'
DECLARE @sP nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @D1 DateTimeOffset(0) = '1901/1/1 01:01:01 -04:30';
DECLARE @D2 DateTimeOffset(0) = '1902/2/2 02:02:02 -04:30';
SET @sP = N'ProductLevel=' + 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(25),SERVERPROPERTY('PRODUCTLEVEL')) + 
    ', ProductVersion=' + 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(25),SERVERPROPERTY('PRODUCTVERSION'));
BEGIN TRY
SET @D1 = DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(2017, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -4, 00, 0);
-- SET @D2 = DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(2017, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -4, 30, 0);
-- When uncommenting the above line, error 289 occurs
SET @sP = @sP + N', @D1=' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @D1) + N', @D2=' + 
CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @D2);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @sStatus = N'Err Num = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(12), ERROR_NUMBER());
    SET @sStatus = @sStatus + N', ' + N'Err Severity = ' + 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(12), ERROR_SEVERITY());
    SET @sStatus = @sStatus + N', ' + N'Err State = ' + 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(12), ERROR_STATE());
    SET @sStatus = @sStatus + N', ' + N'Line Num = ' + 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(12), ERROR_LINE());
    SET @sStatus = @sStatus + N', ' + N'Msg: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    SET @sP = @sStatus;
END CATCH
SELECT @sP AS Result;

-- Result with SET @D2 = ... commented out:
-- ProductLevel=RTM, ProductVersion=12.0.2569.0, @D1=2017-01-01 01:01:00.0 -04:00, @D2=1902-02-02 02:02:02.0 -04:30

-- Result with SET @D2 = ... uncommented (remove leading '--'):
-- Err Num = 289, Err Severity = 16, Err State = 6, Line Num = 11, Msg: Cannot construct data type datetimeoffset, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.
```

When the 9-th parameter to DateTimeOffsetFromParts is not 0, I get error 289: 'Cannot construct data type datetimeoffset, some of the arguments have values which are not valid'. However, offset minutes from 0 to 59 should be valid input, including 30.

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimeoffsetfromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), you'll find: "For specified offset arguments, DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS expects values for both arguments, and **both values positive or negative**." (In other words, -30 for the minute offset if the hour offset is -4, though obviously this doesn't matter for 0 minute offset.)

Comment: I read that but did not catch on. Thanks for the explanation! Makes sense now.

Comment: @r4r4 Please consider posting a self answer or deleting your question, now that you know the answer (and it's not really a bug but a misunderstanding of the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

As ZLK pointed out, input arguments 8 and 9 in DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS need to have the same sign: both positive, or both negative. The proper line in the code is therefore:

```
 SET @D2 = DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(2017, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -4, -30, 0);
```